# how to convert my php code (with SyntaxHighlight ) to image(like jpeg or png)

Tags: php

I want to share my php source code with my friends but I do not want them copy or modify the code 
So .. I want to convert my source code( with SyntaxHighlight) to image (like png or jpeg) in my hard disk
can any one tell me there is open source project which will help me do it?
thank you

Comment: You know they could just use OCR to get the text back out of the image, right?

Comment: Take a screenshot of your text editor.

Comment: If you give them an image of your code they can either use a) OCR or b) Sit down and type it in!. So if you do not want them to copy it or modify it, just do not give it to them in the first place!

Comment: What does "share" mean in this context?

Comment: the share means I can post my code (image format such as jpeg , png)to my album in flickr

Comment: Ｉ　ｍean convert php code to picture instead converting picture to the php code thanks

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have the code highlighted in HTML format, in which case what you're actually looking for is a way to convert HTML to an image. Which is exactly what [wkhtmltoimage](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) does.

Comment: Fast! Convert your answer to an image, before the OP copies it.

Comment: thanks but how can I convert my  php code to html format which has Custom font